# How to set background-color html table cells with a different data which show in table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

i have using d3.js to create a html table but i have some problem. how can i set a html table background with a another data within  
this is an example code i have use to create a html table and it's data.
i want table show value in matrix and cells background color will depend on cmat

```
    var matrix = [
[11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
[ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
[ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
[ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];
var cmat = [['red','green','orange','blue'],['blue','green','red','orange']
        ,['green','red','blue','orange'],['orange','blue','red','green']];
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(matrix)
        .range(cmat);
var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
    .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

    td.data(cmat).style(
        "background-color", colorScale(d));
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you elaborate on "how can i set a html table background with a another data"? What data exactly?

Comment: most likely you want to color the background based on the value of the cell, conditional formatting

Comment: @Andrew Lohr, Sorry for my ambiguity in my question i want to set cells value with matrix array and cells background colod will depend cmat array

Comment: @rioV8 i can set background color based on value of the cell but i cant set background color by a other data which i binding with colorScale function.

Comment: then create a matrix with `{value, color}` objects, you can fiddle a lot with the indices of cell and parent but this the easiest

Comment: @rioV8 you mean array of object right? var matrix = [ [{value,color},{},{},{}]]